# Incorrect order of cells in UITableVIew objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a problem while filling up the tableview with cells.

There's my array, with which should my cells initiated

```
items = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
             @"http://feeds.test.com/home", @"Home",
             @"http://feeds.test.com/publications", @"Refcardz and Guides",
             @"http://feeds.test.com/agile", @"Agile Zone",
             @"http://feeds.test.com/big-data", @"Big Data Zone",
             @"http://feeds.test.com/cloud", @"Cloud Zone",
             @"http://feeds.test.com/database", @"Database Zone",
             @"http://feeds.test.com/devops", @"DevOps Zone",
             @"http://feeds.test.com/integration", @"Integration Zone",
             @"http://feeds.test.com/iot", @"IoT Zone",
             @"http://feeds.test.com/java", @"Java Zone",
             @"http://feeds.test.com/mobile", @"Mobile Zone",
             @"http://feeds.test.com/performance", @"Performance Zone",
             @"http://feeds.test.com/webdev", @"Web Dev Zone",
             nil];
```

So order of created cells SHOULD LOOK like this:

Home - Refcardz and Guides - Agile Zone - Big Data Zone - Cloud Zone - Database Zone - DevOps Zone - Integration Zone - IoT Zone - Java Zone - Mobile Zone - Performance Zone - Web Dev Zone

BUT cells ordered in this way
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtRtA.png)

Here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath, if it helps:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)sourceTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *myIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [sourceTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *curName = [webSitesNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [curName copy];
    if([self.cellSelected containsObject:indexPath]){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I really have no idea why there's such kind of strange behavior.
How to improve my code to view all the cells in order like in my array?

Comment: Dictionaries don't have indices. so objectAtIndex on a dictionary will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a dictionary and dictionary is not a ordered collection. You have to use an array instead. Convert the items into an array instead.

Another option is to add another level of dictionary to your existing dictionary and use the keys such as "0", "1", "2"...etc

E.g.
items = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@{@"url":@"http://feeds.test.com/home", @"title":@"Home"}, @"0",
@"url":@"http://feeds.test.com/publications", @"title":@"Refcardz and Guides"}, @"1".....

Basically you use the index as the key into the dictionary and value is another dictionary with the url and the title keys.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works great!